# How to determine Team Project Uri from project folder

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm making a `c#` application where the user provides a `c++` project directory that is under source control on `TFS` 2012. I need to determine the Team Project Uri so that I can use the `TFS API` to modify labels on that c++ project.

The only thing I've found is to navigate to the `$tf` folder that is created and parse the `localversion.tf1` file, but it's not easy to read in. Is there a better way to determine this?

Or perhaps a way to read the file using the Microsoft Team Foundation library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use the [VersionControlServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx) class from TFS Client Object Model.

You can find an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883959.aspx).